# How to make a input field when click on a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make input field instead of comma separated text from my bellow table.

In my bellow code when click a table cell it add its own text string into a input field like `A1,A2,A3,A4`

But I would like to output each field as input field and value of the field from the table cell where clicked. Actually I want to save each filed value to database. That's why I need input field.

```
<input type="text" class="some_class" value="text of the the cell" >
```

Can someone help me to modify my code?

My table is look like

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/1rpfkdfr/)

```js
$(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false,
    isHighlighted;
  $("#ticketLayout .select")
    .mousedown(function () {
      isMouseDown = true;
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      ticketName();
   calculate();
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })

    .mouseover(function () {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
        ticketName();
  calculate();
      }
    });

  $(document)
    .mouseup(function () {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });
});
 
 function ticketName(){ 
var count = $("#ticketLayout td.highlighted").length;
$(".ticket-count").text(count);

var ticketValue = "";
$("#ticketLayout td.highlighted").each(function(){
    ticketValue += $(this).text() + ",";
});
$(".selected-ticket").val(ticketValue);
}

//Calculate Price
function calculate()
{
 var qty = document.getElementById("ticket-count").innerText;
 var value = document.getElementById("item-price").innerText;
 var result =  value * qty;
 
 $(".total-price").val(result);
}
```

```css
table .select {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
table .selected {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

table td.highlighted {
  background-color:#60fc60;
}

.ticket-panel{
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticket-panel">
  <p>Ticket Fare: <span id="item-price" class="item-price">450</span>Taka</p>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="ticketLayout">
       <tbody>
         <tr><td class="select">A1</td><td class="select">A2</td><td></td><td class="select">A3</td><td class="select">A4</td></tr>
         <tr> <td class="select">B1</td><td class="selected">B2</td><td></td><td class="select">B3</td><td class="select">B4</td></tr>
        
</tbody>  
</table>
  
       <form action="booking.php" method="post">
        <div class="ticket-data">

  <div class="seats-container"></div>

        <p>Your Seat:<input id="tickets" name="ticket_no" type="text" class="selected-ticket" /></p>
        <p>Seat No: <span class="ticket-count" id="ticket-count" > </span></p>
        <p>Total Price: <input type="number" name="total-price" id="total-price" class="total-price" /></p>
        <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: maybe add input fields before to each table and hide/show them on click?

Comment: no it should add to my bellow form where output shown

Comment: document.createElement() or $('<input type="text" class="some_class" value="text of the the cell" >') and append the new node you have?

Comment: can you show me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what i understand from your questions that you need to create a new input for each highlighted `<td>` instead of appending the text to another input value.
This can be done by changing the `ticketName()` function to be like this :

```
function ticketName(){ 
    var count = $("#ticketLayout td.highlighted").length;
    $(".ticket-count").text(count);
    $('.seats-container').html('');
    $("#ticketLayout td.highlighted").each(function(){
        $('.seats-container').append('<div>Seat : <input name="seats[]" type="text" class="some_class" value="'+$(this).text()+'" ></div>');
    });
}
```

Also you need to change your html code to put the inputs container div inside the `<form>` so that all the input will be submitted with the form data.. so you have to append this to your form :

```
<div class="seats-container"></div>
```

Comment: how to set max select 5 seat at a time

Comment: //add this line to the mousedown function :
    .mousedown(function () {
      if($('td.highlighted').length>=5)
      {
         return false;
      }
    })

Comment: yes it works but it does not deselect and click feature disabled

Comment: Update it again to include this line after isMouseDown=true
.mousedown(function () {
      isMouseDown = true;
      if($('td.highlighted').length>=5) { return false; }
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      ticketName();
   calculate();
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })